# What does [[:print:]] means on a directory path?

Tags: regex, bash, shell, command-line, glob

What does `[[:print:]]` means on the following code?

```
echo 255 > /sys/devices/platform/[[:print:]]*/hwmon/hwmon[[:print:]]*/pwm1
```

What is the difference between using `[[:print:]]*` and only `*`?

```
echo 255 > /sys/devices/platform/*/hwmon/hwmon*/pwm1
```

Is there any known name of this feature, or any place I could read and understand more about?

Comment: `[[:print:]]` is a feature shared between (BRE and ERE standard-compliant) regexes and globs; it matches any printable character.

Comment: So `[[:print:]]*` in a glob matches a printable character, followed by zero-or-more other characters, which may or may not be printable. (Whereas for a regex, in `[[:print:]]*` the `*` modifies the `[[:print:]]` to match zero-or-more printable characters).

Answer (score 3):

`[[:print:]]`, in either a glob-style expression or a POSIX-compliant regex, matches any printable character.

The reference for (the simplified, single-character case of) glob expressions is https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_13_01; it references the regular expression portion of the standard at https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_03_05 as being authoritative for square-bracket expressions, which describes `[:print:]` as one of the character-class expressions that all locales must provide. The details of this specific class are then provided in https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap07.html#tag_07_03_01.

Answer (score 3):

`[[:print:]]` is a Posix class recognized by all engines today as matching up to
144,544 or less, Unicode characters as of Unicode 14.
The raw representation of that is this UTF-8/32 regex based on UCD.
This matches up to *ALL* of them. Some engines match less, doesn't matter though,
it is always this or less, never more as of V14.

```
[\\a-zA-Z0-9\t-\r-/:-@\[\]-`{-~\\ -¬®-ÿĀ-ͷͺ-Ϳ΄-ΊΌΎ-ΡΣ-ԯԱ-Ֆՙ-֊֍-֏֑-ׇא-תׯ-״؆-؛؝-ۜ۞-܍ܐ-݊ݍ-ޱ߀-ߺ߽-࠭࠰-࠾ࡀ-࡛࡞ࡠ-ࡪࡰ-ࢎ࢘-ࣣ࣡-ঃঅ-ঌএঐও-নপ-রলশ-হ়-ৄেৈো-ৎৗড়ঢ়য়-ৣ০-৾ਁ-ਃਅ-ਊਏਐਓ-ਨਪ-ਰਲਲ਼ਵਸ਼ਸਹ਼ਾ-ੂੇੈੋ-੍ੑਖ਼-ੜਫ਼੦-੶ઁ-ઃઅ-ઍએ-ઑઓ-નપ-રલળવ-હ઼-ૅે-ૉો-્ૐૠ-ૣ૦-૱ૹ-૿ଁ-ଃଅ-ଌଏଐଓ-ନପ-ରଲଳଵ-ହ଼-ୄେୈୋ-୍୕-ୗଡ଼ଢ଼ୟ-ୣ୦-୷ஂஃஅ-ஊஎ-ஐஒ-கஙசஜஞடணதந-பம-ஹா-ூெ-ைொ-்ௐௗ௦-௺ఀ-ఌఎ-ఐఒ-నప-హ఼-ౄె-ైొ-్ౕౖౘ-ౚౝౠ-ౣ౦-౯౷-ಌಎ-ಐಒ-ನಪ-ಳವ-ಹ಼-ೄೆ-ೈೊ-್ೕೖೝೞೠ-ೣ೦-೯ೱೲഀ-ഌഎ-ഐഒ-ൄെ-ൈൊ-൏ൔ-ൣ൦-ൿඁ-ඃඅ-ඖක-නඳ-රලව-ෆ්ා-ුූෘ-ෟ෦-෯ෲ-෴ก-ฺ฿-๛ກຂຄຆ-ຊຌ-ຣລວ-ຽເ-ໄໆ່-ໍ໐-໙ໜ-ໟༀ-ཇཉ-ཬཱ-ྗྙ-ྼ྾-࿌࿎-࿚က-ჅჇჍა-ቈቊ-ቍቐ-ቖቘቚ-ቝበ-ኈኊ-ኍነ-ኰኲ-ኵኸ-ኾዀዂ-ዅወ-ዖዘ-ጐጒ-ጕጘ-ፚ፝-፼ᎀ-᎙Ꭰ-Ᏽᏸ-ᏽ᐀-᚜ᚠ-ᛸᜀ-᜕ᜟ-᜶ᝀ-ᝓᝠ-ᝬᝮ-ᝰᝲᝳក-៝០-៩៰-៹᠀-᠍᠏-᠙ᠠ-ᡸᢀ-ᢪᢰ-ᣵᤀ-ᤞᤠ-ᤫᤰ-᤻᥀᥄-ᥭᥰ-ᥴᦀ-ᦫᦰ-ᧉ᧐-᧚᧞-ᨛ᨞-ᩞ᩠-᩿᩼-᪉᪐-᪙᪠-᪭᪰-ᫎᬀ-ᭌ᭐-᭾ᮀ-᯳᯼-᰷᰻-᱉ᱍ-ᲈᲐ-ᲺᲽ-᳇᳐-ᳺᴀ-ἕἘ-Ἕἠ-ὅὈ-Ὅὐ-ὗὙὛὝὟ-ώᾀ-ᾴᾶ-ῄῆ-ΐῖ-Ί῝-`ῲ-ῴῶ-῾ -\ ‐-\ \ -\ ⁰ⁱ⁴-₎ₐ-ₜ₠-⃀⃐-⃰℀-↋←-␦⑀-⑊①-⭳⭶-⮕⮗-ⳳ⳹-ⴥⴧⴭⴰ-ⵧⵯ⵰⵿-ⶖⶠ-ⶦⶨ-ⶮⶰ-ⶶⶸ-ⶾⷀ-ⷆⷈ-ⷎⷐ-ⷖⷘ-ⷞⷠ-⹝⺀-⺙⺛-⻳⼀-⿕⿰-⿻　-〿ぁ-ゖ゙-ヿㄅ-ㄯㄱ-ㆎ㆐-㇣ㇰ-㈞㈠-ꒌ꒐-꓆ꓐ-ꘫꙀ-꛷꜀-ꟊꟐꟑꟓꟕ-ꟙꟲ-꠬꠰-꠹ꡀ-꡷ꢀ-ꣅ꣎-꣙꣠-꥓꥟-ꥼꦀ-꧍ꧏ-꧙꧞-ꧾꨀ-ꨶꩀ-ꩍ꩐-꩙꩜-ꫂꫛ-꫶ꬁ-ꬆꬉ-ꬎꬑ-ꬖꬠ-ꬦꬨ-ꬮꬰ-꭫ꭰ-꯭꯰-꯹가-힣ힰ-ퟆퟋ-ퟻ豈-舘並-龎ﬀ-ﬆﬓ-ﬗיִ-זּטּ-לּמּנּסּףּפּצּ-﯂ﯓ-ﶏﶒ-ﷇ﷏ﷰ-︙︠-﹒﹔-﹦﹨-﹫ﹰ-ﹴﹶ-ﻼ！-ﾾￂ-ￇￊ-ￏￒ-ￗￚ-ￜ￠-￦￨-￮￼�------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------]
```

Comment: Not "all engines today", no -- some regex engines do not support POSIX character classes. Python's, most notoriously. (Also, directory paths are glob expressions / fnmatch expressions; they use the same character class syntax as regular expressions, but that doesn't mean they're the same thing).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I don't know if POSIX is copyrighted, but using `[[:print:]]` and saying posix is not supported is infringement as far as regex constructs. I could be wrong but I doubt it.

Comment: The _standard text_ is copyrighted, but that doesn't have anything to do with keywords used by an implementation. In many major jurisdictions, "functional elements" necessary for compatibility _cannot_ be protected by copyright -- copyright is in those jurisdictions restricted to "expressive" elements. So I really don't understand the point you're trying to make, or what copyright has to do with any of this.

Comment: A standards body has more standing based on _trademark_ to stop someone from using their name without complying with the standard, but that's about claiming to be compliant while not being compliant; not about adopting only a subset of elements of a standard while also not claiming compliance. If someone doesn't claim compliance with a standard or otherwise use the standards body's trademark, the standards body has no legal grounds to be involved at all.

Comment: I'm not sure what your implementation of a regex engine being protected by copyright has to do with anything I've said above. What _exactly_ is the infringement you allege Python's re engine would be guilty of if my assertions were accurate (if in fact the preceding sentence accurately summarizes your argument)?

Comment: Okay, then we have nothing to discuss.